# Segmentation fault on reallocation of memory but why?

Tags: c, memory-efficiency, memory

I have been learning to code in C from this amazing resource http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/

I am on exercise 17. Basically creating your own simple database using Malloc. I modified the exercise to come up with my own arbitrary size database. So far I have been on the right track. But I have had to deal with this segmentation fault nightmare and I don't know where and why its happening in my code.

If some of you C geniuses could kindly look into my code and point out what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Particularly in the function Database_Set and Database_ExpandSize. Inside Database_Set, I keep track of rows count to see if it exceeds maxrows and call Database_Expand to reallocate a new memory space of bigger size. Before this I shift everything from old address to a temporary address using memcpy.

Please look at my code below. The code is running fine till I set 8 rows but when I try to set a 9th row in my database. The size increases from 8 to 16 but and causes a "segmentation fault". I am definitely doing something absurd in Database_Expand but I am don't know what. You can also try running the entire code in your C compiler. I am running it on my Mac Terminal by using Make.

Also after running the code through valgrind, showed me some memory leaks loss of some 16k bytes in Expand_Size. How do I correctly free the old memory space while reallocating?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 2

struct Address
{
    int pid;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database
{
    //for arbitrary size database, we need to allocate it on the Heap'
    int maxrows;
    int rowCount;
    struct Address* addressRows;
};

struct Connection
{
    struct Database* db;
    FILE* file;
};

void Database_Load(struct Connection* conn)
{
    int rc = fread(conn->db,sizeof(struct Database),1,conn->file);
    if(rc!=1)printf(" could not load the database ");
}

// This is the first step. You first open the database by allocating space for connection and database structures
// Next you check for the mode type and open the file assigining it to connection
struct Connection* Database_Open(const char* filename)
{
    struct Connection* conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
    if(!conn)printf(" memory error ");

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if(conn->db == NULL)printf(" mem error ");

    //setting up arbitrary size database
    conn->db->maxrows = MAX_ROWS;
    conn->db->rowCount = 0;
    conn->db->addressRows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * conn->db->maxrows);
    conn->file = fopen(filename,"w");
    /*else
    {
        conn->file = fopen(filename,"r+");

        if(conn->file)
            printf(" loading the database.. ");
            Database_Load(conn);
    }*/
    if(!conn->file)
    {
        printf(" failed to open the file ");
        return NULL;
    }
    return conn;
}

// Initialize all the pids of address structures in the database
void Database_Create(struct Connection* conn)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < conn->db->maxrows; i++)
    {
        struct Address* addr = conn->db->addressRows + ( sizeof(struct Address) * i );
        addr->set = 0;
        addr->pid = i;
    }
}

int Database_ExpandSize(struct Database* db)
{
    /*
     allocate a temp address row stuct
     */
    struct Address* tempAddrRows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * db->maxrows);
    struct Address* startAddress = tempAddrRows;  //to bring back tempAddressRows back to the start, keep a track of its starting address
    struct Address* incrementalAddress = tempAddrRows;
    struct Address* dbAddrRowTemp = NULL;

    /*
     copy everything from original addressRows to temporary incremental address which points to tempAddressRows
     */
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < db->maxrows; i++)
    {
        dbAddrRowTemp = db->addressRows + (sizeof(struct Address) * i);
        memcpy(incrementalAddress,dbAddrRowTemp,sizeof(struct Address));
        incrementalAddress += sizeof(struct Address);
    }

    //sanity check, all looks fine
    for(i = 0; i < db->maxrows; i++)
    {
        struct Address* check = tempAddrRows + (sizeof(struct Address) * i);
        printf(" \n for temp addr row, pid, set, name, email %d %d %s %s \n ",check->pid,check->set,check->name,check->email);
    }

    //reallocate temp address to double size and bring it back to start address
    tempAddrRows = realloc(tempAddrRows,db->maxrows * 2 * sizeof(struct Address)); //realloc frees the previous memory block ie previous allocations of tempAddrRows is freed!
    tempAddrRows = startAddress;

    //make the max rows double the size and assigne dbAddressRows to point to newly allocated tempAddressRows
    db->maxrows *= 2;
    db->addressRows = tempAddrRows;
    return 1;
}

void Database_Write(struct Connection* conn)
{
    rewind(conn->file);
    int rc = fwrite(conn->db,sizeof(struct Database),1,conn->file);
    if(rc!=1)printf(" memory error in database write ");
    rc = fflush(conn->file);
    if(rc == -1)printf(" could not be flushed ");
}

void Database_Set(struct Connection* conn,int id,char* name,char* email)
{
    conn->db->rowCount++;
    if(conn->db->rowCount > conn->db->maxrows)
    {
        printf(" row increased max row size, expanding the array from %d to %d \n ",conn->db->maxrows,conn->db->maxrows*2);
        if(Database_ExpandSize(conn->db) == 0)
        {
            printf(" failed to resize the array ");
            return;
        }
    }

    struct Address* addr = conn->db->addressRows + ( sizeof(struct Address) * id );

    if(!addr)
    {
        printf(" addr is null in Set ");
        return;
    }

    if(addr->set == 1)
    {
        printf(" already set the id \n ");
        return;
    }

    addr->set = 1;
    addr->pid = id;

    printf(" setting for %s with address %p \n",name,(void*)addr);

    char* res = strncpy(addr->name,name,MAX_DATA);
    if(!res)printf(" could not set the name ");


    res = strncpy(addr->email,email,MAX_DATA);
    if(!res)printf(" could not set the email ");
}

void Database_Get(struct Connection* conn,int id)
{
    struct Address* addr = conn->db->addressRows + (sizeof(struct Address) * id );

    if(!addr)
    {
        printf(" addr is null in Get ");
        return;
    }
    printf(" for id %d ",id);
    printf(" \n name %s",addr->name);
    printf(" \n email %s",addr->email);
}

void Database_Delete(struct Connection* conn,int id)
{
    struct Address* addr = conn->db->addressRows + (sizeof(struct Address) * id );

    if(!addr)
    {
        printf(" addr is null in Get ");
        return;
    }
    addr->set = 0;
}

void Database_List(struct Connection* conn)
{
    int i =0;
    for(i = 0; i < conn->db->maxrows; i++)
    {
        struct Address* addr = conn->db->addressRows + (sizeof(struct Address) * i );
        printf(" \n inside list address for id %d -> %p, setId %d \n ",i,(void*)addr,addr->set);
        if(addr->set == 1)
        {
            printf(" id %d \n",addr->pid);
            printf(" name %s \n",addr->name);
            printf(" email %s \n",addr->email);
        }
    }
}

void Database_Close(struct Connection* conn)
{
    if(conn)
    {
        if(conn->file)fclose(conn->file);
        if(conn->db)free(conn->db);
        free(conn);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3) printf(" enter correct parameters in form ./HeapDatabase db.dat c ");

    char* filename = argv[1];
    struct Connection* conn = Database_Open(filename);
    Database_Create(conn);
    Database_Write(conn);

    Database_Set(conn,0,"j","b");
    Database_Set(conn,1,"p","k");
    Database_Set(conn,2,"fd","ewew");
    Database_Set(conn,3,"ew","as");
    Database_Set(conn,4,"ewq","ewe");
    Database_Set(conn,5,"bn","we");
    Database_Set(conn,6,"de","de");
    Database_Set(conn,7,"m","a");
    //Database_Set(conn,8,"wee","qweqwe");
    Database_List(conn);
    Database_Close(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your `Database_ExpandSize()` function:

```
struct Address* startAddress = tempAddrRows;
...
//reallocate temp address to double size and bring it back to start address
tempAddrRows = realloc(tempAddrRows,db->maxrows * 2 * sizeof(struct Address)); 
tempAddrRows = startAddress;
```

You first reallocate your data with twice the size but then you overwrite the pointer it with the old (now invalid, because *realloc frees the previous memory block ie previous allocations of tempAddrRows is freed!*) pointer. This leaks the newly allocated block (as there is no pointer to it) and makes `tempAddrRows` a dangling pointer. Any access to the memory pointed to by it results in undefined behaviour.

To fix both issues remove the assignment `tempAddrRows = startAddress;`.

You should also check whether `realloc` returns `NULL` to handle any error during memory allocation. Note that when `realloc` indeed does return `NULL` the original memory block is **not** freed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That doesn't solve the segmentation fault error.